# Initialise helper class in a react functional component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-functional-component

The class methods which are passed as args from the functional component, are kept 'in memory' and doest not reflect the updated state. I can reinitialise on state changes but wish to avoid it.

```
const MyFunctional = (props) => {
    const [state,setState] = useState(0);

    const helper = useRef();

    useEffect(()=>{
        helper.current = new HelperClass(onSuccess,onFailure);
    },[])
    
    /* wish to avoid */

     useEffect(()=>{
        helper.current = new HelperClass(onSuccess,onFailure);
    },[state])



    const onSuccess = (result) =>{
       
       /* Here state == 0 */

    }

    const onFailure = (error) =>{
       /* Here state == 0 */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an additional ref to be able to use the latest values in an async callback.

Either

- [grab `react-use`'s `useLatest`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLatest.md) hook,
- [write one yourself according to the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function),
- or steal this trivial reference implementation:

  ```
  function useLatest(value) {
    const ref = useRef(value);
    ref.current = value;
    return ref;
  };
  ```

```
const MyFunctional = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const latestStateRef = useLatest(state);
  const helper = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    helper.current = new HelperClass(onSuccess, onFailure);
  }, []);

  const onSuccess = (result) => {
    console.log(latestStateRef.current);
  };

  const onFailure = (error) => {
    console.log(latestStateRef.current);
  };
};
```